# Define custom type in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below type:

```
create or replace TYPE t3_data AS OBJECT (
    vk   NVARCHAR2(12),
    pl   VARCHAR2(2000),
    dt   NUMBER,
    ay   CHAR(10),
    ao   CHAR(10),
    an   VARCHAR2(4000),
    r    NUMBER,
    c    CHAR(10)
);
```

Which I use in a function like the below:

```
FUNCTION pick_values RETURN t3_table PIPELINED
```

The relation between t3_data and t3_table is the below:

```
create or replace TYPE t3_table IS
    TABLE OF t3_data;
```

Is there a way to define t3_data and t3_table inside a package in which I already have the function defined?

Comment: Do you care whether `t3_data` is an object type or a record?  What version of Oracle are you using (in older versions, pipelined table functions would be restricted to using SQL types rather than PL/SQL types)?

Comment: @JustinCave not sure if I understand the question. What's the difference? I'm using Oracle 12.1.

Comment: Object types are SQL types.  They potentially have much more functionality-- inheritance, member functions, etc.  Records are PL/SQL types that are just a collection of fields.  My guess if you aren't aware of the differences and you're just using the object for a pipelined table function that you're not using any of the additional functionality of an object type.

Comment: It's a good idea to use meaningful attribute names rather than `vk`, `pl`, `dt` etc. Also the standard type for strings is `VARCHAR2`, not `CHAR` which is mostly a source of bugs and best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types are SQL types so they cannot be c reated in PL/SQL.  You can, however, define a record type in a package rather than an object type and you should be able to use that record type to define a pipelined table function

```
create or replace package test_pkg
as
  type t3_data_rec is record (
    vk   NVARCHAR2(12),
    pl   VARCHAR2(2000),
    dt   NUMBER,
    ay   CHAR(10),
    ao   CHAR(10),
    an   VARCHAR2(4000),
    r    NUMBER,
    c    CHAR(10)
  );
  
  type t3_table is table of t3_data_rec;
  
  function pick_values 
    return t3_table pipelined;
end;
/

create or replace package body test_pkg
as
  function pick_values 
    return t3_table pipelined
  is
    l_rec t3_data_rec;
  begin
    l_rec.vk := N'foo';
    pipe row( l_rec );
  end;
end;
/

select *
  from table( test_pkg.pick_values );
```